# Adjust Email notification for failed login attempts after the second try

Tags: keycloak

I'm aware of the email notifications for failed login attempts in Keycloak. Currently, I receive an email notification each time there's a wrong email or password entered. However, I'm looking to customize this feature so that I receive the notification only after the second unsuccessful attempt.

Implement a modification to the system to trigger email notifications for failed login attempts after the second try

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.